# testing if component text is copy-able or not

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I'm writing a test to try and see if a react component has its text copy-able (the component doesn't have `user-select: none;` in css).

```
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(element);
```

The problem is that even if i disable text select or not (`user-select: none;`), i still can get the range to select my text (although it's not selectable in the actual component) e.g. `range` contains my component text.

Also, when trying to actually copy the text, it seems like `document.execCommand("copy")` is not working. Running `document.queryCommandSupported("copy")` returns `false`.